# what language does gclass use?

Tags: programming-languages

first, I read the info in mcp info page and it says nothing about the language. then I asked my friends and they said they cant tell and im trying to create a .gclass file for application.

Comment: This is totally confusing. Please give us some context. Where do these .gclass appear? You found the mcp download page. Nice, but that doesn't mean we even know what mcp is in this context. So adding that link would help.

Comment: What's mcp? What did you download? You may want to add more details.

Comment: What am I looking at there? This is even more confusing. Please understand we're really not inside your head and you must tell us what you're thinking and working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gclass uses noveascript language for its source but mostly java and lua

Comment: What is "noveascript"? A typo? Casual googling reveals absolutely nothing about it or similarly named languages.

Comment: you seriusly dont know noveascript